# How to process a text file separated by spaces using logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, config

My log file

> maker  model  mileage  manufacture_year  engine_displacement  engine_power  body_type  color_slug  stk_year  transmission  door_count
>   seat_count  fuel_type  date_created  date_last_seen  price_eur
>   ford  galaxy  151000  2011  2000  103      None  man  5  7  diesel  2015-11-14 18:10:06.838319+00  2016-01-27 20:40:15.46361+00  10584.75
>   skoda  octavia  143476  2012  2000  81      None  man  5  5  diesel  2015-11-14 18:10:06.853411+00  2016-01-27 20:40:15.46361+00  8882.31
>   bmw    97676  2010  1995  85      None  man  5  5  diesel  2015-11-14 18:10:06.861792+00  2016-01-27 20:40:15.46361+00  12065.06
>   skoda  fabia  111970  2004  1200  47      None  man  5  5  gasoline  2015-11-14 18:10:06.872313+00  2016-01-27 20:40:15.46361+00  2960.77
>   skoda  fabia  128886  2004  1200  47      None  man  5  5  gasoline  2015-11-14 18:10:06.880335+00  2016-01-27 20:40:15.46361+00  2738.71

Error is below

> [2018-03-23T11:35:20,226][ERROR][logstash.agent]Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::PluginLoadingError", :message=>"Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'txt'. Are you sure this is correct?

My conf file is below

> input {file {path => "/home/elk/data/logklda.txt"start_position => "beginning"
>   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"}}
>   filter{txt {separator => "  "columns => ["name","type","category","date","error_log"]}}
>   output {elasticsearch {hosts => "localhost"index => "logklda"document_type => "category"}stdout{}}

Comment: How does your logstash configuration looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter txt does not exist. From your configuration, it seems you want to use the [csv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html). In your case, replacing txt by csv, the configuration would look like this:

```
csv {
  separator => " "
  columns => ["name","type","category","date","error_log"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are filter called "txt"is not existing. I think you must check this logstash guide site and correct your code. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html